# Cannot get PHP to download CSV to the user

Tags: php

When I use this code to download content to the CSV file and to the user, It just displays the Query to the website...

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
$counter=1;

// open file and put herder to csv file
$file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($file, array('id','name','test1','test2'));
// put content to csv file
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    fputcsv($file, array($counter++,$row['name'],
                         ($row['test1']!=-1)?$row['test1']:'null',($row['test2']!=-1)?$row['test2']:'null'));
}
$csv_name=(isset($_GET['device'])&&$_GET['device']!='')?$_GET['device']:"all_devices";
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;'.
       'filename='.$csv_name.'_'.date('Y-m-d').'.csv');
} else {
  echo "No device found";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

aside by move `header()` call in front of `fputcsv()`, you can use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#refsect1-function.header-notes) to get around, by calling `ob_start()` at the beginning and `ob_end_flush()` at the end of your script.